# How can I convert a PDF document to a Publisher document

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-publisher

I have a PDF document with advanced formatting that was created in InDesign that I want to convert to a Publisher document. I have already tried converting the PDF into Word usding the built in Export function on Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, and only the header, footer and a few words came out. Using Word copying and pasting is very tedious as only the text gets selected and not the formatting or images. I do not have Adobe InDesign on my computer.

Is there anyway to do this?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, the process of converting to PDF is pretty much a one-way path since so much tends to get thrown away when you do so.

You are lucky to even get most of the text.

PDF is basically an image format who's job is to ensure that the output is consistent come what may, anything else is a bonus.